# Simple pop-up after p:selectBooleanCheckbox?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have several pages where I am using PrimeFaces checkbox in this way:

```
<p:column>
  <f:facet name="header">
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{Bean.allChecked}">
      <p:ajax process="@this" update=":form:table" listener="#{Bean.handleAllChecked}"/>
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
  </f:facet>
 ...
</p:column>
```

I'd like to bring up an info pop-up dialog saying "This will select all items!" with only one "OK" button. How would I do that?

Have in mind that there are several pages with the same behaviour, and I'd like to avoid copy/pasting the same code over and over again if possible.

Comment: `onclick=alert(...` ? =D

Comment: Thanks. I need this only when it is selected, and not when unselected. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible... You just need to check if the checkBox is already checked...Take a look in Makky answer, if you still need a JS function, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achived by using `primefaces` `commandButton` and `Confirmation dialog`

in your xhtml file

```
<f:facet name="header">
  <p:commandButton value="Select All" actionListener="#{testBean.handleAll}">
        <p:confirm header="Select All" message="This will select all items?" 
         icon="ui-icon-alert" />
  </p:commandButton>
</f:facet>
```

Add confirmation dialog code (you can create one file and just include in any xhtml )

```
<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">
            <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button"
                styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
            <p:commandButton value="No" type="button"
                styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
        </p:confirmDialog>
```

**Managedbean**

```
public void handleAll(ActionEvent event){
        System.out.println("called only when selected yes");
    }
```

The method `handleAll` will only be called if user clicks "`Yes`" otherwise it won't do anything.

I hope that help